# Get mouse click coordinates within a class - python

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to get mouse click coordinates within a class. I have done this before using tkinter, but I am have trouble integrating it within a more complicated context (within a class)

My current code switches between two graphs and this works well, however I want to be able to get mouse click coordinates on the second graph.

Here is my code so far (tried to make it minimal working code):

```
import math
import scipy  as sp
from scipy import signal
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.widgets import Cursor
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

matplotlib.use( 'tkagg' )

from tkinter import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
# Implement the default Matplotlib key bindings.
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler


# make some data:
x_axis = np.arange(0, 10, 0.1)
data = np.sin(x_axis)

zero_crossings = np.where(np.diff(np.sign(data)))[0]
y_axis = [0, 0, 0, 0]


def find_nearest(array, value):
    idx = (np.abs(array-value)).argmin()
    return array[idx]

def config_plot():
    tk, ax = plt.subplots()
    ax.set(title='Count the steps! \n Are there 10 steps??')
    return (tk, ax)


class matplotlibSwitchGraphs:
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.fig, self.ax = config_plot()
        self.graphIndex = 0
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.master)  
        self.config_window()
        self.draw_graph_one()
        self.frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

    def config_window(self):
        self.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.on_key_press)
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self.master)
        toolbar.update()
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        self.button = Button(self.master, text="YES", command=self._quit)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.button_switch = Button(self.master, text="NO", command=self.switch_graphs)
        self.button_switch.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def draw_graph_one(self):
        self.ax.clear() # clear current axes
        self.ax.plot(data)
        self.ax.plot(zero_crossings, y_axis, marker='o', linestyle='none')
        self.ax.set(title='Check the data \n Are the touchdowns and toeoffs in the right spots? \n are there 10 steps?')
        self.canvas.draw()

    def draw_graph_two(self):
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(data)
        self.ax.set(title='Instructions: \n 1) click the incorrect step \n 2)Click where it should be')
        self.ax.plot(zero_crossings, y_axis, marker='o', linestyle='none')
        self.canvas.draw()
        #Want to get imput from 2 mouse clicks!!!! 

    def on_key_press(event):
        print("you pressed {}".format(event.key))
        key_press_handler(event, self.canvas, toolbar)

    def _quit(self):
        self.master.quit()  # stops mainloop

    def switch_graphs(self):
        # Need to call the correct draw, whether we're on graph one or two
        self.graphIndex = (self.graphIndex + 1 ) % 2
        if self.graphIndex == 0:
            self.draw_graph_one()
        else:
            self.draw_graph_two()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    matplotlibSwitchGraphs(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Ideally, in the end I want the first click to remove one of the markers (toeoff_cut or touchdown_cut) and for the second click to place it in a new spot... but for now just getting the coordinates of the clicks would be helpful!

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: if you put in question `"minimal working code"` which we could run (to see problem) then we can try to modify it.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. As an aside, you appear to be mixing multiple naming conventions. Class names should generally follow the `CamelCase` style, variable and function names the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I am new here, I tried to provide a minimal working code now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to get mouse click then you have to use `"button_press_event"` instead of `"key_press_event"` which is for keyboard keys.

```
self.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.on_key_press)
```

Or you can use both - and you can assign to different methods

```
self.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.on_key_press)
self.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.on_button_press)
```

and

```
def on_button_press(self, event):
    print('-----')
    print('button:', event.button)
    print('xdata, ydata:', event.xdata, event.ydata)
    print('x, y:', event.x, event.y)
    print('canvas:', event.canvas)
    print('inaxes:', event.inaxes)
```

More type of events you can find in [matplotlib.pyplot.connect](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.connect.html) or [Event handling](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/users/event_handling.html)

(but I seem there is no `DoubleClick` for mouse)

---

If you want to disconnect event then you have to keep value returned by mpl_connect

```
 # connect

 self.button_press_id = self.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.on_button_press)

 # disconnect

 self.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.button_press_id)
```

This way you can use different functions for differnt plots.

---

Minimal working code:

```
from tkinter import * # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (
    FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


# (not so) random data
import random
random.seed(0) # will give the same values in every execution
Z_filt_1 = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10)]
Z_filt_2 = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(10)]


class MatPlotLibSwitchGraphs:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master

        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(5, 4), dpi=100)
        self.ax = self.fig.gca() #config_plot()

        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, self.master)  
        self.config_window()

        self.graphIndex = 0
        self.draw_graph_one()

    def config_window(self):
        toolbar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self.master)
        toolbar.update()

        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

        print('connect')
        self.canvas.mpl_connect("key_press_event", self.on_key_press)
        self.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.on_button_press)

        self.button = Button(self.master, text="QUIT", command=self._quit)
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)
        self.button_switch = Button(self.master, text="CHANGE PLOT", command=self.switch_graphs)
        self.button_switch.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def draw_graph_one(self):
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(Z_filt_1)
        self.ax.set(title='First Plot')
        self.canvas.draw()

    def draw_graph_two(self):
        self.ax.clear()
        self.ax.plot(Z_filt_2)
        self.ax.set(title='Second Plot')
        self.canvas.draw()

    def on_key_press(self, event):
        print('key:', event.key)

    def on_button_press(self, event):
        print('-----')
        print('button:', event.button)
        print('xdata, ydata:', event.xdata, event.ydata)
        print('x, y:', event.x, event.y)
        print('canvas:', event.canvas)
        print('inaxes:', event.inaxes)

    def _quit(self):
        #self.master.quit()  # stops mainloop
        self.master.destroy() # works better then `quit()` (at least on Linux)

    def switch_graphs(self):
        # Need to call the correct draw, whether we're on graph one or two
        self.graphIndex = (self.graphIndex + 1 ) % 2
        if self.graphIndex == 0:
            self.draw_graph_one()
        else:
            self.draw_graph_two()

def main():
    root = Tk()
    MatPlotLibSwitchGraphs(root)
    root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**BTW:** [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

Comment: This works great, thanks! How would I go about saving the x coordinates that are clicked rather than printing them?

Comment: assing to class variable - ie. `self.x = event.x` and then you can use `self.x` in any other method in class.

Comment: Sorry I am new to classes so I need a little extra help. Eventually I want something like: If button is pressed, take that x value and remove it from the array, then replot the graph. Sorry if I am asking too many questions - I just want to know if I need to call the x value within the class or outside of it

Comment: when you press mouse button then program runs function `on_button_press()` and you get `event.x` (and `event.xdata`) - so do all inside `on_button_press()`